# How to implement jquery fullcalendar library in my custom drupal 7 module?

Tags: 7

I am going to implement the 'Full Calendar' JQuery library in my custom drupal module, and event data fetching from url as JSON formate, but design becomes hazy, this is my 'template code'.

NOTE: All the jquery and css files are loaded successfully.

```
<?php global $base_path;?>

<link href="<?php echo ( $base_path.drupal_get_path ( 'module', 'sogh_full_schedules' ) . '/css/fullcalendar.css' ); ?>" />

<link href="<?php echo ( $base_path.drupal_get_path ( 'module', 'sogh_full_schedules' ) . '/css/fullcalendar.print.css' ); ?>" />


<script src="<?php echo ($base_path.drupal_get_path ( 'module', 'sogh_full_schedules' ) . '/js/moment.min.js' ); ?>"> </script>

<script src="<?php echo ($base_path.drupal_get_path ( 'module', 'sogh_full_schedules' ) . '/js/jquery.min.js' ); ?>"> </script>

<script src="<?php echo ($base_path.drupal_get_path ( 'module', 'sogh_full_schedules' ) . '/js/fullcalendar.min.js' ); ?>"> </script>

<?php 
/* $today_schedules = array();
$today_schedule_list = ($form ['full_schedules'] ['#value']); */
?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: Drupal.settings.basePath + '?q=sogh_full_schedules/json',
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                jQuery('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<div id='script-warning'>
    <code>php/get-events.php</code> must be running.
</div>

<div id='loading'>loading...</div>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You need to describe exactly what your problem is; saying _design becomes hazy_ doesn't say much. Also, you need to explain exactly where you are using that code (e.g. a template file used by a module); the code you are showing is not the code you use in a module, since a module doesn't mix JavaScript and PHP like that.

Comment: Also, if the problem is that you don't know how to write a module, this question is too broad. We cannot teach things like that, since we should copy what the documentation already says.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question, this is my template coding, question has modified. Thanks